# Killing vectors and isometry

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, symmetry, vector-fields

Let $X=x\partial_{t}+t\partial_{x}$ and $Y=y\partial_{t}+t\partial_{y}$ be Killing vectors on Minkowski $(-,+,+,+)$. It can be shown that $[X,Y]$ is also Killing. I get the following:
\begin{equation}
[X,Y]=(x-y)\partial_{t}+x\partial_{y}.
\end{equation}

What isometry is this Killing associated with?

Comment: You know your last term is wrong, as it is not antisymmetric in *x,y*. Have you learned about boosts and rotations?

Comment: I think it should be $(x-y)$ too. I know it has to do with rotational symmetry. The problem is, I have confusion about the Killing $U=\partial_{t}+\frac{1}{r}\partial_{\phi}$ In Schwarzschild metric. I thought if I understand the Minkowski case, The Schwarzschild would follow from the first case using the same reasoning

Answer (score 1):

You did not evaluate you commutator correctly. Your two boosts commute to a rotation on the *x,y* plane,
$$[X,Y]=  [x\partial_{t}+t\partial_{x},  y\partial_{t}+t\partial_{y}]=x\partial_y-y\partial_x,$$
and  all three annihilate $x^2+y^2+z^2-t^2$.